# Single MySql query to get list of user who did like the posts which is liked by me

Tags: mysql

MySql table: `likes`

```
+----+---------+--------------+
| id | post_id | liked_by_uid |
+----+---------+--------------+
|  1 |   10    | 56           |
|  2 |   10    | 51           |
|  3 |   11    | 51           |
|  4 |   11    | 57           |
|  5 |   12    | 58           |
|  6 |   13    | 58           |
+----+---------+--------------+
```

1. My user id(uid) is 51
2. There are 4 posts (post_id 10,11,12,13)
3. I did like post 10 and 11 (liked_by_uid is 51)
4. I want the list of `uid` (56,57) because of they liked posts (10, 11) which is liked by me.

I can do using two query

```
SELECT post_id FROM likes WHERE liked_by_uid='51' //51 is me
```

$ids = "'10','11'"; getting from 1st query

```
SELECT liked_by_uid FROM likes WHERE post_id IN($ids);
```

desired uids(56,57) are getting from 2nd query

How can do it using single query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT liked_by_uid FROM likes WHERE post_id IN
    (SELECT post_id FROM likes WHERE liked_by_uid='51')
```